# Can you someone support me to use ordinal in while loop in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, while-loop, ordinal

I am having a difficult time figuring ordinal in the program below. I need to use the ordinal in the loop statement. When I print statement, It print out backward like 3rd, 2nd, 1st, and so on.

I tried changing my loop statment from (number -= 1) to (number += 1) but that would make infinite while loop. Can someone give me feedback on what I can do here? Thank you.

```
class Integer
 def ordinal
  case self % 10
when 1
  return "#{self}st"
when 2
  return "#{self}nd"
when 3
  return "#{self}rd"
else
  return "#{self}th"
end
end
end 

puts "Let's play a numbers game."
print "How many numbers would you like to enter? >"
number = gets.chomp.to_i

while number >= 1

    print "\n\nEnter the #{number.ordinal} positive integer:"

    user_int = gets.chomp.to_i

    number -= 1

if user_int % 3 == 0

    print "#{user_int} is divisible by 3."
else 
    print "#{user_int} is not divisible by 3."
end 
end
```

puts "\n\nEnd of the Game"

Comment: Consider writing `def ordinal; h = { 1=>"st", 2=>"nd", 3=>"rd" }; "%d%s" % [self, h.fetch(self % 10, "th")]; end`.
Then `1231.ordinal #=> "1231st"; 1232.ordinal #=> "1232nd"; 1239.ordinal #=> "1239th"` and so on. See [Hash#fetch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch).

Comment: Don't forget that it's `11th`, `12th` and `13th`.

Comment: And you might also want to fix `-27.ordinal #> "-27rd"` (hint: use `abs`)

Answer (score 1):

First I'd suggest you to patch `Integer` class in this way:

```
module MyIntegerPatch # <------ a custom module
  def to_ordinal # <------ to_ordinal is better
      case self % 10
    when 1
      return "#{self}st"
    when 2
      return "#{self}nd"
    when 3
      return "#{self}rd"
    else
      return "#{self}th"
    end
  end
end

Integer.include MyIntegerPatch # <------ "patch" the class
```

Then for your loop just use a [Range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Range.html):

```
(1..number).each do |n| # <---- a range here
  puts "\n\nEnter the #{n.to_ordinal} positive integer:"
  user_int = gets.chomp.to_i
  if user_int % 3 == 0
      puts "#{user_int} is divisible by 3."
  else 
      puts "#{user_int} is not divisible by 3."
  end 
end
```

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful.

Comment: :+1: While patching should always be done with careful consideration, if you _have_ to do it, `include`/`extend`-ing the custom module is strictly the better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try below, use the ruby style `times` to control

```
class Integer
  def ordinal
    case self % 10
    when 1
      "#{self}st"
    when 2
      "#{self}nd"
    when 3
      "#{self}rd"
    else
      "#{self}th"
  end
 end
end

puts "Let's play a numbers game."
print 'How many numbers would you like to enter? >'
number = gets.chomp.to_i

number.times do |time|
  print "\n\nEnter the #{(time + 1).ordinal} positive integer:"
  user_int = gets.chomp.to_i
  if user_int % 3 == 0
    print "#{user_int} is divisible by 3."
  else
    print "#{user_int} is not divisible by 3."
  end
end

puts "\n\nEnd of the Game"
```

Comment: Thank you, Auli for helping me solve this. It worked.